# Store directory and its files in a two dimensional array VB2008

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I have a folder structure like below. I want to store the directories and the files inside it.... in an array.

I have done storing the directories in an array but i am uncertain if i am storing its files in an array also because i cannot call it directly when files(0), files(1), etc.

Is it possible if i will store each file in a two-dimensional array

wherein files(j)(k) where j=directory and k=file. ?

Well, what i just wanted to resolve is to loop in each file and compare their contents...and maybe one way to resolve is to do two-dimensional array.

Correct me if i'm mistaken. Thanks.

```
parent                'I stored it as an array
|
|---dirA              'dir(0)
|    |---fileA.txt           'file(0)
|    |---fileB.txt           'file(1)
|
|---dirB              'dir(1) 
|    |---file2A.txt          'file(0)
|    |---file2B.txt          'file(1)
|
|---dirC              'dir(2)
     |---file3A.txt          'file(0)
```

Here is my code:

```
Option Explicit On
Imports System 
Imports Scripting
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Public Class Form1

Public Shared directory(), files(), FILE_NAME1, FILE_NAME2 As String
Public Shared count As Long
Public Shared counter1, counter2 As System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection(Of String)
Public Shared dirsize, filesize, i, j As Integer

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim parentinfo As New DirectoryInfo("C:\parent")

    Dim dirsize As Integer = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories("C:\parent").Length
    'ComboBox1.Items.Add(dirsize) --> This is for me to check for the no.of folders in the parent

    ReDim directory(dirsize)

    '------------------------------------------------------
    'Access the Parent Folder and stores the directory in an array[]
    '------------------------------------------------------

    For Each dir As FileSystemInfo In parentinfo.GetFileSystemInfos()
        directory(i) = dir.Name
        i += 1
        ReDim Preserve directory(i)
    Next dir

    '------------------------------------------------------
    ' In this part, I will Re-iterate in each folder and access all the files inside it
    '------------------------------------------------------
    For k = 0 To dirsize - 1

        Dim childinfo As New DirectoryInfo("C:\parent\" & directory(k))

        'Count the no.of files contained in each folder
        Dim location = New DirectoryInfo("C:\parent\" & directory(k))
        Dim filesize = location.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)

        'Initialize and re-define files
        ReDim files(filesize.Length)
        Dim fs As Integer = 0

        'Re-iterate in each file inside the sub-folder and store it as an array
        For Each data As FileSystemInfo In childinfo.GetFileSystemInfos()

            '------------------------------------------------------
                                   'This is where I am storing the file as an array
            files(fs) = data.Name  'I am reluctant here if this is storing as an array

            'ComboBox1.Items.Add(files(fs)) --> This is for me to output array of files

            lst.Items.Add(files(fs))

            '------------------------------------------------------

            fs += 1
            ReDim Preserve files(fs)
        Next data

    Next

    '---------------------------------------------------------------
    'This is for me to loop over  the parent folder and its files, but it is 
    'throwing an error at runtime
    'My purpose for this is to compare the contents of each file
    'I haven't included my code for comparing contents because it will be very long
    '---------------------------------------------------------------

    For c = 0 To dirsize - 1 'number of directories in the parent folder

        Dim direct As String = "C:\parent\" & directory(c)
        Dim DirectoryEntries As String()
        Dim NumberOfFiles As Double

        DirectoryEntries = System.IO.Directory.GetFileSystemEntries(direct)

        NumberOfFiles = UBound(DirectoryEntries)

        For b = 0 To NumberOfFiles 'number of files in the subfolder (for example: dirA)

            'this should where i compare file1 and file2
            'in this part it throws an error-->Index was outside the bounds of the array

            FILE_NAME1 = "C:\parent\" & directory(c) & "\" & files(b) 

        Next

    Next

End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like a list of lists would be better, performance wise. You should try to avoid arrays for dynamic data, which folder structure is. Since you are planning to compare, a `Dictionary(Of String, FileSystemInfo)` would probably be more suitable, where key is your `filePath`. Depends on what you are comparing though.

Comment: @rmm04: Then dictionary approach works best I think. So you have a one-dimensional structure, which takes care of a tree structure. Create two dictionaries for each side of comparison and go one by one, via `TryGetValue` method.

Comment: create two dictionaries of each side..which means comparing the files inside two folders or comparing each files inside one folder? because i will loop over all sub-folders...

Comment: such a relief with this one... i am able to reduce my code by a half with producing the same result as above. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.